# Multiple monitor app interface duplication issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 22.10

I am using a laptop and 2 monitors connected to it (laptop display is set as main). While using those monitors, in some situations (didn't observe a cause to trigger this effect), when an application is maximized and focused on secondary display - it's interface is duplicated on the main display like in the gif below:
[image]

As you can see, when I focus on the app on the monitor it is duplicated on the laptop display, which isn't a normal behavior.

Ubuntu 22.10, kernel version 5.19.0-26-generic

This is my `xrandr` output in case it might help:

```
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+120 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND2 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+120 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND3 connected 1920x1200+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
   1920x1200     59.88*+
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   1920x1080     59.88  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Comment: Logging in using Xorg instead of Wayland display server fixed the issue for me. Here you can see how to switch to Xorg: https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland

Answer (score 0):

Logging in using Xorg instead of Wayland display server fixed the issue for me.

Here you can see how to switch to Xorg: https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland